# Rstudio hangs when trying to load caret package

Tags: r, package, loading, rstudio, r-caret

I can successfully install caret and its dependencies, but I cannot load. When I tried loading caret, it loaded required package lattice, and then tried to load required package ggplot2 and just stopped. No error message, but never went back to cursor, couldn't type any commands. I had to force close Rstudio.

Then I tried loading ggplot2 first, and that worked, so I tried to load caret again. Then it got hung up trying to load lattice like it got hung up on ggplot2 before, no error message, no blinking cursor. Had to force close.

Then I tried loading ggplot2 and lattice first. Those both worked. Tried to load caret, don't get any messages saying its trying to load dependencies, no error messages, no blinking cursor. It just hangs up.

I have tried downloading caret from 3 mirrors.

I'm using the latest version of Rstudio on Windows 7 64bit.

Thanks for the help, Jordan

Comment: What happens if you try to load `caret` directly in R?

Comment: Sorry Pascal, not sure what you mean. I've only been using R for a few weeks. Do you mean downloading caret outside of R, and then installing it from a local drive?

Comment: i.e. not through RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I just figured out was to uninstall R and Rstudio and reinstall them.  Then I installed caret and its dependencies from a CRAN mirror I know I had not used previously. Probably could have gotten away with just deleted caret and all of its dependencies and reinstalling from another mirror, but I reinstalled R just to have a clean slate.